# Multi clients - one server using Python

Tags: python-3.x, udp

I have a question about how to make the server add a client to a list right after the client connected? In UDP, I know that only after the client sends the message to the server then the server knows who sent the message (address). But what I want here is to make the server know who connected, and add to the list before receiving the message.
Is that possible for UDP?

Thank you for answering my question, my English is not so good so please ignore my grammar.

In the terminal, I initiate the terminal with
python3 ChatServer.py 9099 (9099 is random number I assigned to be port number)
Then to call multiple clients, I run this command twice
python3 ChatClient.py hostname 9099

If you need I'll send my code.

Answer (score 0):

> But what I want here is to make the server know who connected, and add to the list before receiving the message. Is that possible for UDP?

With TCP there is an initial connection setup where no data are transferred - so it is possible to know the client before receiving application data.

With UDP though it all starts with the first data packet received, i.e. with the first actual message sent by the client. This means UDP itself provides no way to know the client before receiving the first message.

Of course, one might gain some knowledge through a different way, like some configuration about which clients are expected. In this way these clients need to explicitly bind to the IP and port expected by the server though, because otherwise some random source port will be used which is not expected by the server.